# Componente QDateEdit só aceita datas a partir de 1752

Tags: c++, qt

Olá,
preciso cadastrar dados com datas de 1500 e 1600 mas o componente QDateEdit só aceita datas a partir de 1752.
Tem como alterar o componente? Existe algum outro componente que substitua este?
Já tentei alterar a propriedade minimumDate mas o mínimo é este mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Por defeito a class QDateEdit aceita datas no intervalo 14 Setembro de 1752 até 31 Dezembro de 7999. No entanto este intervalo pode ser alterado, bastando para isso utilizar o método [setMinimumDate(const QDate &min)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#minimumDate-prop) ou o método [setDateRange(const QDate &min, const QDate &max)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#setDateRange)

Por exemplo, com o setDateRange seria algo assim:

```
QDateEdit dtE;
QDate minDate(1500, 1, 1);
QDate maxDate(1600, 12, 31);
dtE.setDateRange(mindDate, maxDate);
```

Da [documentação](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#minimumDate-prop)

> By default, this property contains a date that refers to September 14,
>   1752. The minimum date must be at least the first day in year 100, otherwise setMinimumDate() has no effect.